# 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'

Tags: c#, oracle

I run this command 'desc v$sga' in Visual Studio 2019 using c# for Oracle version 12c

```
cmd.CommandText = "desc v$sga";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get an error:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

although I use a query

```
select column_name 
from all_tab_columns  
where table_name = 'v$sga';
```

It returns an empty result.

I don't know if anyone else has had this problem.

Comment: Please format you question, not getting anything.

Comment: Well, `desc v$sga` doesn't sound like an SQL statement to me. Even if you are able to run it in some shell, it doesn't mean it's SQL.

Comment: so how can i get the names of the columns in that table ?

Comment: i used it and i mentioned in the problem details :v

Comment: IF you do `select distinct table_name from all_tab_columns` do you see your table name in the results?

Comment: you should try V_$SGA (uppercase), as v$sga is a synonym of V_$SGA,

Comment: i can't see table_name='v$sga' in all_tab_columns but i can 'select * from v$sga' I don't know how it can do that

Comment: [DESCRIBE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040) is a SQL\*Plus *client* command, not SQL. It works in some other clients. If you do that in SQL Developer you can see the underlying query it actually runs.

Comment: @quangminh - (a) it's a unquoted identifier so it will be in uppercase in the data dictionary, as `'V$SGA'`; and (b) it's a synonym so it will be in `all_synonyms` not `all_tables`, and you need to look for the real table that points to, again in uppercase. As gsalem said earlier.

Comment: Actually, my purpose is to get the names of the columns of the V$SGA table but I get the results from this table but I can't get the names of the columns in this V$SGA table

Comment: Yes, because it isn't a table, it's a a synonym (alias) for `V_$SGA`; and that's a view not a table, but will still show up in `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: ohh i get it i'm an idiot haha thank for anwser

Comment: `DESC` is not a valid SQL statement. That's probably something that can run in the "SQL*Plus" client only.

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a SQLPlus command, not a SQL command. You cannot use it outside of SQLPlus or some client that emulates SQLPlus.

As for querying the dictionary, fixed object view names (`v$`, `gv$`) are synonyms. The actual views are `v_$sga` (with an underscore). And you should request the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY priv and use the DBA_ (dba_tab_columns) instead of the ALL_ views so you eliminate permissions as a reason for not seeing something.